# What happened at the end of Wasurenagumo?

Tags: wasurenagumo

So at the end of **Wasurenagumo**, we have Mizuki:

> With the spider girl and Shu. Spider girl makes Mizuki fall into the giant spider, Shu doesn't seem to care, then we're back in the city and the spider girl is with Shu and she looks like Mizuki now (or other way around?)

So did,

> Mizuki die (and Shu didn't care)? Was there an ulterior motive for killing Mizuki, who seems to have simply been at the wrong place at the wrong time with the wrong person?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shopkeeper said it was over if he got caught in the web, which happened. You could see the blue glare under the guy's eyes, which means he wasn't himself anymore. He snapped out of it before because the girl got hurt, but after he got caught in the web again he was being controlled(?) again.So maybe the spider-girl is now manipulating Suzuri and he's thinking she is Mizuki

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Suzuri was caught by the web after Mizuki fell into the lake. My guess is that she was eaten or whatever by the spider-mum and the girl who was with Suzuri was the spider-girl. Because, if you did notice, at the scene where she let Mizuki fall from the web, the spider-girl looked more mature and grown up. So she probably cut her hair to look like Mizuki afterwards but I doubt that the girl with Suzuri at the ending was Mizuki.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the monster-wife the older shopkeeper seemed to have at the end, the story was more of a "Selkie" story.

The Spider-mom would attack the village if not given a sacrifice, until the monk sealed her in the lake.

The Spider-girl would take control of people using her webs, and force them to walk into the lake to feed her mom.

It seems that Suzuri was originally going to be sacrificed, but the Spider-girl had A: Fallen for him, or B: wanted to repay his kindness and thus fed Mizuki to the Spider-mom and took her role as Suzuri's companion in Mizuki's form.

Lots of legends, both Japanese and European tell of women that were originally spirits, animals, or both, that can take on human form to be the wife of a human, such as Selkies or the Legend of the Swan. Usually the myths end with the spirit wanting to return home, either leaving the husband or in some versions taking him with them.

As aficionados of old books, legends and myths, the two book-sellers would be familiar with these legends, as hinted at with the older man's "Wife" seen in the last few shots.

Whether there was any romantic reasons for the Spider-girl staying with Suzuri doesn't matter; most likely, she was using him to eventually find more food for her trapped mother. It's mostly left up to the viewer what the Spider-Girl's intentions were and why she is staying with Suzuri in Mizuki's form.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers before this are pretty spot on. "Don't fall in the web". Both Suzuri and Geppou were "ensnared"/infatuated in some way by monster people; Suzuri by the Spider girl and Geppou by an unknown one (slime/mist?)

Answer (score 0):

well I don't think so, cause the spider girl is more likely a youkai which means some spirit ghost creature. I believe the girl at the end is Mizuki transformed or possessed by the spider girl. Just the last frames make me believe its likely so, its starts as Mizuki grow longer hair changes hair colour and so on.

Answer (score -1):

I think Mizuki and spider-girl changed places 
spider-mon  didn't seen mad, and gently go back to the lake after Mizuki's Fall .

Comment: Do you have any evidence of this?